# how to make $scope.$broadcast work in Ipad?

Tags: angularjs, ipad, mobile-devices

I have two controllers, say controller1 and controller2.
I have function called function1 defined in controller1.
When I try to call function1 from controller2 using $scope.$broadcast, it works fine in desktop browsers.

But it does not enter into `$scope.$on` which is written in controller1 in Ipad browser chrome.

I have tried different ways for this to work. importing controller1 into controller2 and so on. But then variables in the browser does not reflect its values.

`$scope.$on` in **controller1:**

```
$scope.$on("con1function", function(event, activity, action) {

    $scope.function1(activity,'dashboard');
})
```

**Controller2:**

```
$scope.con2function = function() {
    $scope.$broadcast("con1function",data[0], '');
}
```

can anyone tell me what is wrong here? Or what is the way in which I can make this work for the Ipad as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `$rootScope.$broadcast("con1function","Hi there")` to broadcast the message and `$scope.$on()` to recieve it.

If your controllers are not related (as parent or child) then just `$scope.broadcast` or `$scope.emit` may not work.

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
 myApp.controller('controller1', function ($scope,$rootScope) {
     $scope.sendMessage = function(){
      console.log("in sendMessage");
      $rootScope.$broadcast("con1function","Hi there")
     }
    });
  myApp.controller('controller2', function ($scope,$rootScope) {
      console.log("in controller2");
      $scope.$on("con1function", function(event, activity) {
        console.log('dashboard',activity);
      });
    });
```

Also make sure that required controllers are loaded in your script or HTML.

Comment: Thank you for the great help.It is working as expected.